# Forgotten password in Joomla administrator

Tags: joomla

I forgot my password in my webpage joomla administrator login.
webpage nem com administrator
I know that admin is the username, but I don't know the password.
How can I know my password or give a new password?

Comment: change it in the database

Comment: log into the datbase through phpmyadmin or some other interface, locate the table/row/column and update the password.

Comment: I assume you mean something like create an appropriately hashed password using the Joomla password API and change to that?  Or register a new user to get an appropriately hashed password and copy that? Because putting a plaintext password in the user table would make the situation much much worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this documented at http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F

Answer (score 1):

You can edit configuration.php via FTP, or you can edit the database, usually done via PhpMyAdmin.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F