# reset joomla super admin password. Step-by-step manual

Tags: joomla, passwords

How can I reset super admin password for Joomla cms? 
Please give me step-by-step instruction))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forgotten password in Joomla administrator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911512/forgotten-password-in-joomla-administrator)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the step by step in this link with more detailed information, just check
 the version of your joomla! site:

- [Recover or reset your admin password](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F)